# Editor and mobile build version are different in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game that a game object that follows our character on 2D platforms.
Over time, the game object increases its speed.
I managed to do that by using this

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(gameObject.transform.position, kr.transform.position, speed);
```

"kr" is our character.
And this script is on the game object that follows our character.

In the editor, I tried some values to find out what's best and applied them.
But when it comes to the android build version, it is way too slow. So I had to increase the speed values like 150x or 200x.
But when I do that in the editor tab, it is fast as speed.
How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because of performance issue that happens use this instead`Speed * Time.deltatime`